# Formatting Problems after inserting a title page into the BioMed Central Template

Tags: formatting, titles, pdfpages

I am working on a document using the Biomed Central Template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/biomed-central-article-template/gcgcxphtpccx
and copypasted the first basic title page from The Overleaf Instructions: https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_5)%3A_Customising_Your_Title_Page_and_Abstract
and as a result the title section of the regular first page of the template is moved to the left, which makes the document unreadable.

[image: Here you can see the moved title...]

This problem only appears the first page after the titlepage. Since the Template requires a submission as one big .tex-file i would be very thankful for any recommendations how to fix this.

Comment: Please clarify: If you are submitting an `article` to BioMed Central, why do you want to insert a title page (such as in a  `book`  or  a `thesis`) ?

Comment: The use of a professional magazine template like BioMed Central is mandatory for the thesis, but a title page is still required, so i thought it was possible to use the corresponding Latex function titlepage.

Comment: Journal publication classes like the biomed one are written to make it hard (preferably impossible) for authors to customise the style as they aim to force the journal style, so completely unsuited to being used with a tutorial on how to customise page layout.

Comment: You happen to know any ways besides hardcoding a title page from scratch?

Comment: Does your thesis have chapters?

Comment: i just used sections and subsections for that

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to document a procedure for adding a title page to an existing document (although I doubt `bmcart` would be useful for writing a thesis).

**Opcion 1** Assuming the submission is a single `pdf` file, as I don't think a thesis will fit in a single `.tex` file (as shown in Option 2): eg. figures need to be submitted separately.

You will need to create three files:

(1) The thesis itself formatted as you see fit. (file `MyThesis.tex`)

(2) The cover, often following the guidelines of the institution. (file `TitlePage.tex`)

(3) The main program to integrate the above documents in a book twoside format. (file `main.tex)`

For this example, put all three files in the same working directory.

**(1)** Compile and debug the cover and the thesis.

**(2)** As a final step, run `main.tex` to merge them in  a single pdf.

[image: a]

This is the file `TitlePage.tex`

```
 %%File TitlePage.tex

\documentclass[12pt]{article} % 

\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]{geometry}% narrow margins <<<<<
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty} % supress all headers <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
   \begin{center}
    \vspace*{5cm}
    
    \textbf{\Large Thesis Title}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    Thesis Subtitle
    
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    
    \textbf{\large Author Name}
    
    \vfill
    
    A thesis presented for the degree of\\
    Doctor of Philosophy
    
    \vspace{1cm}
    
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    
    Department Name\\
    University Name\\
    Country\\
    Date
    
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This is the file `MyThesis.tex`

```
%% File MyThesis.tex

\documentclass{bmcart}

\usepackage{lipsum} %dummy tex
    
\begin{document}    

\section{Chapter title}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Heading for section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{Heading for sub section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

This is the file `main.tex`

```
%%% File main.tex

\documentclass[twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{pdfpages} % To include the cover and the tesis

\usepackage[left=0cm, right=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}    

\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{TitlePage.pdf}
\newpage\mbox{}\clearpage

\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{MyThesis.pdf}

\end{document}
```

**Opcion 2** Single `.tex` file: file `AllMyThesis.tex`

[image: c]

```
%% File AllMyThesis.tex

\documentclass{bmcart}

\usepackage{lipsum} %dummy tex
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
\begin{document}
%%%************************************************************ added
\titlepage % Output the title page
\begin{center}
    \pagestyle{empty}
        { % Title(s) and author(s)
            \sffamily % Font styling
            {\Huge\bfseries A very long Thesis Title\par} % Book title
            \vspace{16pt} % Vertical whitespace
            {\LARGE Subtitle \par} % Subtitle
            \vspace{44pt} % Vertical whitespace
            {\huge\bfseries  Author Name\par} % Author name
                \vfill              
            A thesis presented for the degree of\\
            Doctor of Philosophy
                \vfill
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}\par
                \vspace{24pt}
                    Department Name\\
                University Name\\
                Country\\
                Date
        }   
\end{center}    
\newpage \pagestyle{empty}\mbox{}\clearpage % blank page        
\setcounter{page}{1} % start thesis with page 1
%%%************************************************************ 

\pagestyle{bmcheadings}     
\section{Chapter title}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Heading for section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{Heading for sub section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!